# Azure Queue Functions | Trigger when multiple queue functions executions with a specific message property ends

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I have 2 different queue functions, they both update different properties of the same database entity (using unit of work pattern).

Each function has his own queue and poison queue. The message of each queue contains the same `entityId`. Both functions need to be executed in parallel.

I would like to execute a hook or similar when there is no more messages in any of the queues (queue-one, queue-one-poison, queue-two and queue-two-poison) where `entityId == xxxx`

My current code for the functions:

```
 [Function("functionone")]
 [ExponentialBackoffRetry(5, "00:00:04", "00:01:00")]
 public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queue-one")] MyMessage message, FunctionContext executionContext)
 { 
     // logic here...
 }
```

What options do I have here?

Comment: You could at least check [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=in-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cv1-model&pivots=csharp). They allow you to orchestrate multiple steps like this. Specifically this would be the fan-out/fan-in pattern.

Comment: @juunas thanks. I already have that in the same code base but this wont allow to know when the enqueued message ends processing, right?

Comment: No, but you could use activity functions in a Durable Functions orchestrator to achieve the same thing.

Comment: that would require to many changes on the existing project